# How to check if section exists in IniParse.parse using Ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

```
require 'iniparse'

conf = IniParse.parse(File.read('my.conf'))
```

How do I check to see if `conf['DEFAULT']` exists before reading it?

Answer (score 1):

You can poke at it with a stick:

```
if (conf.key?('DEFAULT'))
  # Congratulations, there's something there
else
  # Uh-oh, it's missing. Panic?
end
```

Or you can be a bit smarter about it:

```
case (conf['DEFAULT'])
when Hash
  # Great, that's what I was expecting!
when nil
  # Uh-oh, it's missing. Panic?
else
  # That's not what I was expecting.
end
```

Comment: I did this:
unless conf['agent'].nil?
  puts "exists"
end

Comment: The only things logically false in Ruby are `nil` and `false`, so unless you're expecting `conf['agent']` to be *literally* `false` then you can do `if conf['agent']` and be confident it'll work. Since you're looking for strings, hash structures or arrays presumably, `false` isn't something you're interested in anyway.